# The topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is minimal

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a set and $\mathcal{A}$ a base for the topology $\tau$. Consider $\{\tau_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ a family of all topologies over $X$ such that $\mathcal{A}\subset\tau_\alpha$ for any $\alpha\in I$. I want to show that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_\alpha=\tau$.

**Proof:**

**$\tau\subset\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_\alpha$:** Let $u\in\tau$ then, exists $V_\kappa\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $u=\bigcup V_\kappa$ and, as each $V_\kappa$ is a open set for each $\tau_\alpha$ $(\alpha\in I)$, we have that $u\in\tau_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in I$. So, we obtain $u\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_{\alpha}$.

I have troubles with the other contention. Can someone give me a hit to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only true if $\{\tau_{\alpha}\mid\alpha\in I\}$ is the collection of **all** topologies that contain $\mathcal A$.

If that is not the case then the other side does not have to be true.

If that is the case then the other side goes like this:

If $U\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_{\alpha}$ then $U\in\tau$ since $\tau=\tau_{\alpha_0}$ for some $\alpha_0\in I$ and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_{\alpha}\subseteq\tau_{\alpha_0}$

Comment: Yes, is the collection of all topologies.

Comment: @drhab You said, "the other side does not have to be true." Do you have an explicit counterexample?

Comment: What I meant to say is: if $\{\tau_{\alpha}\mid \alpha\in I\}$ is a collection of topologies that contain $\mathcal A$ but does not contain **all** topologies that contain $\mathcal A$ then it not necessarily true that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_{\alpha}$ is a subset of the topology that is generated by $\mathcal A$.

Comment: For instance let it be that $\mathcal A$ is a topology itself such that  not all subsets of $X$ are elements of $\mathcal A$. Evidently $\mathcal A$ is also the topology generated by $\mathcal A$. If $I=\{1\}$ and $\tau_{1}=\wp(X)$ then $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I}\tau_{\alpha}=\wp(X)$ hence is not a subset of $\mathcal A$.